# bad cpu type in executable osx

Tags: macos, bash, makefile, cpu

I'm trying to install the OS X command line tools, and I've tried the beta, and the most recent and nothing is working. Every time I try to use one of the tools something like this happens, my example is make and gnumake as those are what I need right now

-bash: /usr/bin/gnumake: Bad CPU type in executable

-bash: /usr/bin/make: Bad CPU type in executable

note, I am running Yosemite 10.10.4, and my processor is a 2.8 GHz Intel Core i5. If you need any more info be sure to let me know

Comment: Where did you get the command line tools from ?

Answer (score 6):

Your `/usr/bin/make` ELF executable was compiled for a different CPU.

The outputs of below commands should return different processors:

- `file /usr/bin/make`
- `uname -a` or specifically `uname -p`

Comment: file /usr/bin/make give me - /usr/bin/make: Mach-O executable ppc

Comment: and uname -p gives me i386 so, how can i fix this?

Comment: Where did you get the installation package with the tools?

Comment: I got it from the apple developer website

Comment: Also, my hard drive is partitioned with ubuntu and I am using refined to manage the partitions if that matters

Comment: Have you used precompiled versions or built them by yourself? Post a link.

Comment: Have you built the binaries from source code or just installed them?

Comment: I just let the .pkg do the installing

Comment: also, uname -p gave me i386 and name -m gave me x86_64

Comment: Then, you have chosen the wrong package. Unfortunately, I am missing an account on https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ to check for other available options...