# Android Studio-- Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio throws an error while building the project.

the error is :

> Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable.

[image]

The detail error:
[image]

> Bad CPU type in executable --> Can not run command xxx/aapt

Comment: [31251187](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251187/bad-cpu-type-in-executable-osx) maybe similar with this question

Comment: Can refer to this - similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62236184/7680383

Comment: For the M1 Chip sets: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`
Looks like ADB has not been built for the ARM chip set yet. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160004878

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finally I solved this by a little change.

goto the error module and changed the buildToolsVersion to anther(bigger version) in build.gradle file.

rebuild again, the error disappeared.

Comment: Modifying buildToolsVersion resolved this issue. Looks like this is introduced in latest android studio version.

Answer (score 72):

ADB doesn't support ARM, it needs `Rosetta` to run.
I fixed this issue by [installing Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861). Open Terminal and run the following command:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Answer (score 20):

I fixed this error by installing rosetta. Try running this command in your terminal

`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Answer (score 9):

If you using mac m1
First, open the terminal after copy paste this command

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

and after that, press "a"

[image]

Comment: This has already been mentioned in some of the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

Upgrading buildToolsVersion is not work for me, but after upgraded gradle version, the error disappeared.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google() <--don't forget to add this
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3' <--upgrade here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure but seems like updating AGP to 7.1.0 solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Following working fine for *Mac M1 users (If ARM version of android studio is installed --> android-studio-2021.x.x.xx-mac_arm.dmg)):*

Open terminal and install rosetta:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

press **a** and the press enter(return) key.

Now rebuild or sync your project. It will work smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio has built-in installer for M1 ARM64 architecture compatible Java:

`Android Studio -> Preferences -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK -> Download JDK...`

[image: installer]

You feel free to select anything that have `aarch64` tag. Azul for example

After that, run `./gradlew clean` to see, that your project is used fresh ARM supported JDK.

But, for some cases (like `adb`) you need to install rosetta. Other things, like building project going directly through ARM without binary translator.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was other way around. My Mac was on Intel chip but looks like I had downloaded and pointed to JDK 17 that was meant for M1 Chip. I had to go to `Android Studio -> Preferences -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK` and selected an embedded JDK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the AGP need to upgrade.
After upgrading AGP to 7.0.4 , and then it resolve the issue