# Android studio build fails with apple m1 chip

Tags: android-studio, apple-m1

I have new MacBook Pro with the m1 chip, i downloaded the Android studio for apple silicon chip version.
All works fine until the Build process, while build i get error
`Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable`
i spent half day to fix it but without any success, only after i installed Rosetta it successfully finished the build, the question is why i need Rosetta if i install the apple silicon version of Android Studio?
I tried to change gradle plugin version and sdk's, but not helped

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553879/android-studio-cause-error-86-bad-cpu-type-in-executable

Comment: @AtifSayings I saw that one, not helped.

Comment: Did you manage to get anywhere with this?

Comment: @Ljdawson no, since i installed rosseta 2 it works, i don't tried to uninstall it.