# Failed running CMake 3.18.1 on Android

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

Got error when running my project with CMake 3.18.1, I executed the following steps:

1. I added the version requested on build.gradle as `externalNativeBuild { cmake { path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt') version '3.18.1' } }`
2. And also add on defaultConfig `externalNativeBuild { cmake { cppFlags '' } }`
3. Inside CmakeList `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)`

I got error message `[CXX1405] exception while building Json A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/cmake''`

I already clean the project and invalidate cache, but still error. I try increase the version but got many error. thanks

Comment: I found the solution is need remove CMake or .cxx file from your co worker before push to git

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I had same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution is need remove CMake or .cxx file from your co worker before push to git, the issue because generate file. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue. This is an issue with ADB not proving support for Apple M series chipsets.  I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69607332) . Simply install rosetta.

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

[Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160004878)

Answer (score 0):

uninstall and install cmake version 3.18.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).