# Bad CPU type in executable for mediapipe holistictrackinggpu

Tags: android, bazel, apple-m1, tensorflow-lite, mediapipe

I am currently following official instructions to run MediaPipe holistic tracking sample app. [MediaPipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/docs/getting_started/android.md) After MediaPipe installation, I was able to successfully run the 'hello world' example, which is recommended to be tested. However for the mobile app I am getting below error.

> ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_burak/b7cfac50f1c6080dd0242194e8dbaa69/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/gl/kernels/BUILD:321:11: Compiling tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/gl/kernels/mean.cc failed: (Exit 1): clang failed: error executing command (from target @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/gl/kernels:mean) external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang -gcc-toolchain external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 -target ... (remaining 54 arguments skipped)
>
> Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
> src/main/tools/process-wrapper-legacy.cc:80: "execvp(external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang, ...)": Bad CPU type in executable
> Target //mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu failed to build
> Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
> INFO: Elapsed time: 15.290s, Critical Path: 11.95s
> INFO: 274 processes: 140 internal, 134 darwin-sandbox.
> FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

I tried to follow instructions which is given in the official documentation. [mediapipe installing instructions](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/docs/getting_started/android.md) After running

> bazel build -c opt --config=android_arm64
> mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu

throws the above error

WORKSPACE: [workspace file](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/WORKSPACE)

handtrackinggpu: [handtrackinggpu](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu/BUILD)

I am not sure is it related to apple silicon M2

Comment: Isnt the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553879/android-studio-cause-error-86-bad-cpu-type-in-executable)

Comment: I was able to successfully build it after installing rosetta. Initially, I thought I already had rosetta installed, but your method worked perfectly. Thanks @SG_Bazel